# Using PHP, how can I determine which CMS or framework is used?

Tags: php, frameworks, content-management-system

Using PHP, can I find out which CMS or framework is used on a particular website.  Eg Wordpress, Magento or Codigniter, Laravel.

I've tried this approach: http://dailyblogging.org/internet/detect-cms-and-scripts-of-websites/

This is what I actually want, but in code form, not as an online service: http://onlinewebtool.com/cmsdetector.php  This should be a PHP script that does not run as an online service.

What will it take to do this, or at least give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

### Update 2018

Github repo moved:
https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/master/src/apps.json

---

There is a Chrome extension called Wappalyzer.
You can see some regexp which are included in the wappalyzer project for detecting servers, cms and frameworks. 
Maybe you can include this and write a php script that uses this:

https://github.com/ElbertF/Wappalyzer/blob/master/share/apps.json

Comment: Great! This is a really long list. Do you know if they also can detect Wordpress and Magento ed? (r. 3631)

Comment: Yes. There are entires for Magento and Wordpress in the json file

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal, view source

And if you find

/sites/all

/sites/

For including image/javascript/css, its Drupal based site.

Same way, if you find wp_content, its wordpress.

For MVC ftameworks, its difficult to determine as url routing is same for all.

Comment: as soon as i can dislike answers im going to dislike your answer

Comment: @FatihAkgun, sorry, I did not get your point. Can you please explain.

Comment: If you are talking about disliking answers, you are free to down vote. No issues. This way we will know that answer needs improvement. Please feel free to comment/down vote. You are most welcome.:)